# Declare Maven Project as test project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, sonarlint

I have a Maven project with the following structure:

```
- root
  - pom.xml
  - project1
  - project2
  - tck (test compatibility kit)
    - pom.xml
    - src
      - main
        - java
```

The folder `tck` contains a package to test compatibility with requirements and are reused in the tests of project1 and project2 to show that those projects are compliant.
`tck/pom.xml` follows the structure of https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html#the-preferred-way

The issue that I have, is that Maven identifies the `tck` package as a regular package with sources files. Indeed, when I open the Module Settings on IntelliJ, for the module `tck` it detects  `src/main/java` as a source folder and not as a test folder.

It is an issue as I use SonarLint on my project, and in the `tck` folder, they are tests using asserts. Asserts are not recommended in production code and are spotted by SonarLint. I asked a question on https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-running-locally-does-not-catch-parent-pom-xml-rule-exclusion/74764/2, and SonarLint, unlike SonarCloud/Qube, picks its configuration from the Maven project and so if Maven identify it as a source folder and not a test folder, it will report false-positive.

I was wondering if there was a way to declare it clearly on the maven side that this package is a test-package, in order to avoid have the Sonarlint misconfiguration I presented. (I tried the suggestion from the Sonarsource community to change the pom.xml so that the configuration is corrected for all contributors to the project)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven doesn't have a concept of a *project* as a "test project", only test dependencies. You'll need to specifically configure SonarLint to disable that rule for the module.